# jQuery Ajax call - Set variable value on success

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services

I have an application that I am writing that modifies data on a cached object in the server.  The modifications are performed through an ajax call that basically updates properties of that object.  When the user is done working, I have a basic 'Save Changes' button that allows them to Save the data and flush the cached object.

In order to protect the user, I want to warn them if the try to navigate away from the page when modifications have been made to the server object if they have not saved.  So, I created a web service method called IsInitialized that will return true or false based on whether or not changes have been saved.  If they have not been saved, I want to prompt the user and give them a chance to cancel their navigation request.

Here's my problem - although I have the calls working correctly, I can't seem to get the ajax success call to set the variable value on its callback function.  Here's the code I have now.

```
   ////Catches the users to keep them from navigation off the page w/o saved changes...
window.onbeforeunload = CheckSaveStatus;
var IsInitialized;

function CheckSaveStatus() {

    var temp = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "URL.asmx/CheckIfInstanceIsInitilized",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result) {
            IsInitialized = result.d;
        },
        error: function(xmlHttpRequest, status, err) {
            alert(xmlHttpRequest.statusText + " " + xmlHttpRequest.status + " : " + xmlHttpRequest.responseText);
        }

    });

    if (IsInitialized) {
        return "You currently have unprocessed changes for this Simulation.";
    }
}
```

I feel that I might be trying to use the Success callback in an inappropriate manner.  How do I set a javascript variable on the Success callback so that I can decide whether or not the user should be prompted w/ the unsaved changes message?

As was just pointed out, I am making an asynchronous call, which means the rest of the code gets called before my method returns.  Is there a way to use that ajax call, but still catch the window.onunload event? (without making synchronos ajax)

Comment: Just got an email saying that a question of mine from 5 years past was "marked as duplicate".  The "original" question is only a year old.  Go-go time machines!  :) It is a more in-depth response.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Since you need this behavior in the unload event, you will have to make a synchronous call instead. However it may freeze the browser window/tab dependent on how long the call will take, but because you're effectively trying to prevent the user from closing the window...

Add `async: false` to your JSON to make a synchronous call.

Answer (score 8):

An example of jquery page:

```
var html = $.ajax({
  url: "some.php",
  async: false
 }).responseText;
```

Source: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 4):

The thing is that the request to Ajax call is asynchronous. So by the time you are checking you IsInitialized the call has not finished yet.

I suggest specifying your behaviour in the success function.

Basically having synchronous calls with ajax is if not impossible than really discouraged.

Comment: Any suggestions on how I can still catch that window.onbeforeunload event using the asynchronous call?

Answer (score 2):

You could theoretically kill the event (return false) and close the window on success, but I think you would run into Javascript restrictions set by some users, and also just confuse them as to why their window isn't closing.  So, I agree with Pawel Krakowiak, the ajax call itself must be synchronous.

I'll add that you'll want to give the user some notification that you are checking on status (not a popup, please.  one of those nice notification banners at the top of the window) and be sure to set the $.ajax "timeout" option to something more reasonable for this situation, so they aren't waiting forever for the window to close.

Comment: +1, agreed on the notification. Good point.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with attempting to set a property for a data object through the success callback of an ajax request. Using `async: false` didn't solve my issue, either. What I ended up doing was to use a `setTimeout` call outside the ajax call, and set the timeout value to 1, like so:

```
function getSessionid() {  
    $.ajax({  
        type: 'POST',  
        url: 'getSession.php',  
        dataType: 'text',  
        success: function(result){myData.sessionid = result;},   
        error: function(data) {alert("Error!\n" + data);} 
    });  
    setTimeout(function() {alert('sessionid = ' + myData.sessionid);},1);  
}
```

Just having that 1 millisecond delay made all the difference in the world. Without it, the `sessionid` property wouldn't set outside the ajax call, though alerts within the callback showed that it was, indeed, being set. It's something to think about, should you come up against a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the best approach for me was to use the async: false option on my ajax call.  Although I understand Rashack's hesitation for doing this, I think that this situation justifies the means.

Also great point by Jerph about making sure that I don't leave the user hanging while I am trying to verify their status.  That coupled w/ the timeout option is important.

Thanks to everyone who commented.

Answer (score 0):

see here:

http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-dev/browse_thread/thread/40d0e3def47148a0