# Jquery post success variable scope

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, variables, scope

I'm trying to return the ajax success array from one function to another.  For some reason I don't seem to be able to pass the data stored in a variable in the success part of the ajax function into the parent function to return.

I looked at this post to try and figure things out, but not such luck:
[jQuery Ajax call - Set variable value on success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709876/jquery-ajax-call-set-variable-value-on-success)

Thanks so much for any assistance.

Here's a simplified version of the code:

```
// make json_to_return global
var json_to_return;

function loop_through_data(){

  // call the load_days function and put its array data into days_array
  var days_data = load_days(03,2010);

  // I'd like to be able to iterate through days_data here
  //
  //
}

function load_days(selectedMonth, selectedYear){  
                  $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   dataType: "json",
                   url: "../includes/get_availability.php",
                   data: "month=" + selectedMonth + "&year=" + selectedYear,
                   success: function(available_json){
                       json_to_return = available_json;
                   },
                   error: function(msg){
                    alert("error " + msg);
                   }
                 });
               return json_to_return;

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This part of your function happens later:

```
success: function(available_json){
                   json_to_return = available_json;
               }
```

So the variable you're returning is undefined, because the code to set it doesn't happen until the response comes back from the server. Either call the rest of the code to run from your success function, so it'll run when the data's ready, or set `async:false` (less desirable because it locks the browser).

The `async: false` method is like this:

```
              $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               async: false,
               dataType: "json",
               url: "../includes/get_availability.php",
               data: "month=" + selectedMonth + "&year=" + selectedYear,
               success: function(available_json){
                   json_to_return = available_json;
               },
               error: function(msg){
                alert("error " + msg);
               }
             });
```

The better approach:

```
              $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               dataType: "json",
               url: "../includes/get_availability.php",
               data: "month=" + selectedMonth + "&year=" + selectedYear,
               success: function(available_json){
                   loopThroughTheDaysAndDoStuff(available_json);
               },
               error: function(msg){
                alert("error " + msg);
               }
             });
```

Comment: Thanks,  I didn't realize that the return fired before the post completed.  It all makes sense now.

I'll re-jig things so that they happen in the success:

I was hoping to use it as a utility that I could call from multiple functions, but this will work for now.

Answer (score 2):

`$.ajax` is an asynchronous function.

It means that when called, the function keeps executing.

In your code provided `var days_data = load_days(03,2010);` this happens:

- Start an ajax call (asynchronous, function keeps executing)
- return `json_to_return` (undefined)
- `days_data` == undefined
- ajax call finishes, `json_to_return` gets assigned (this can happen in any timespan)

You should rethink your logic, and start coding around the asynchronousity of the `ajax` call.

A first approach might be passing a function (callback) to `load_days` which should be called AFTER the success of the `ajax` call.

Comment: Where is the "keep my new april's fools avatar" button?